# How to use fish shell in cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, fish

Is it possible to use the fish shell with cygwin? I wasn't able to compile the source in cygwin, and I didn't find any precompiled packages. Is there a good reason for not having fish in cygwin?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

fish shell 2.1.0 is now officially supported in Cygwin, it's possible to install it using the default installer.

Answer (score 15):

Here's how I managed to compile [fish](http://fishshell.com) in Cygwin.

#### Step 1: Check that all dependencies are installed

First, make sure we have the following cygwin packages:

- `libncurses-devel`
- `libiconv`
- `autoconf` (not a really a dependency of fish, but we need it for a later step)

#### Step 2: Download and extract the latest source

Next, download the latest source from http://fishshell.com (I used [fish-1.23.1.tar.gz](http://fishshell.com/files/1.23.1/fish-1.23.1.tar.gz)). Extract the source to your directory of choice and cd to it:

```
$ tar zxvf fish-1.23.1.tar.gz -C /usr/local/src/
$ cd /usr/local/src/fish-1.23.1/
```

#### Step 3: Edit `configure.ac` to remove checks for `iconv`

Now for some reason, `./configure` cannot detect `libiconv` properly. To get around the problem we remove the check for it (we'll specify the lib manually later). To do so, we edit `configure.ac` and remove checks for `iconv_open`. Searching for `iconv_open` reveals 3 occurences; we comment them all out. So, from:

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS( iconv_open, iconv, ....)
```

We change to:

```
#AC_SEARCH_LIBS( iconv_open, iconv, ....)
```

#### Step 4: Rebuild and run `./configure`

Next, we rebuild the `./configure` script by running `autoconf` then run the configure script:

```
$ autoconf && ./configure
```

#### Step 5: Edit `Makefile` to include correct path to `curses.h`

Another problem I faced was with `curses.h` -- gcc couldn't find it. A quick search revealed that it's in `/usr/include/ncurses`.

The `Makefile` has a hardcoded include path for it in `CFLAGS`, but it points to `/usr/local/include/ncurses` instead.

So, we edit `Makefile` and change:

```
CFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include/ncurses -std=c99 ....
```

to

```
CFLAGS = -I/usr/include/ncurses -std=c99 ...
```

#### Step 6: Export `LDFLAGS` to link in `libiconv`, and we're ready to compile/install.

Finally, we export the necessary `LDFLAGS` to link in `iconv`, then compile and install!

```
$ export LDFLAGS="-liconv"
$ make && make install
```

#### Enjoy `fish`

```
$ fish
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish
me@home /u/l/s/fish-1.23.1>
```

Comment: +1 I can confirm the steps above should work. I also added `#define HAVE_NCURSES_H 1` in the generated header file `config.h` (for the same reasons stated above)

Comment: I've installed libiconv and set LDFLAGS, but I still get an error: set_color.c:16:20: curses.h: No such file or directory
set_color.c: In function `translate_color':
set_color.c:116: warning: implicit declaration of function `strcasecmp'
set_color.c: In function `main':
set_color.c:333: error: `ERR' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: I saw that error initially too. Have you installed `libncurses-devel` and changed the changed the `-I` path in the `Makefile (step 5)?

Comment: Yes, I even reinstalled libncurses-devel again, just to be sure. Perhaps there's another dependency that was already present in your system? Looking for the error message I've found the following bug report: 
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=928085&group_id=1523&atid=101523

Comment: @muriloq Sounds like `curses.h` is not being included (`ERR` is defined there). Can you have a peek at `/usr/include/ncurses/` and see if it's there?

Answer (score 0):

Check fish issues [#680](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/680) and [#319](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/319) at GitHub, there is everything You need to compile fish on cygwin.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.