# Building Fish 2.0 shell under Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, c++, fish

I wanted to have a fish shell under my cygwin instance and I wanted it so bad that I've event tried to build it but with no luck.

I've gone through all the prerequisites like installing autoconf, clang, ncurses and other needed stuff.

`autoconf` and `./configure` went all good, but when I try `make`, the code won't compile.

I've seen that there is another thread on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/328340/how-to-use-fish-shell-in-cygwin) but it's for the older version 1.23.

So did anyone get this up and running?

Here's the errors from my build:

```
g++ -g -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fno-exceptions -Wall -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DPREFIX=L\"/usr/local\" -DDATADIR=L\"/usr/local/share\" -DSYSCONFDIR=L\"/usr/local/etc\" -DBINDIR=L\"/usr/local/bin\"    -c -o builtin.o builtin.cpp
In file included from builtin_set_color.cpp:13:0,
             from builtin.cpp:397:
fallback.h:97:7: error: previous declaration of ‘char* tparm_solaris_kludge(char*, ...)’ with ‘C++’ linkage
/usr/include/ncurses.h:820:63: error: conflicts with new declaration with ‘C’ linkage
<builtin>: recipe for target `builtin.o' failed
make: *** [builtin.o] Error
```

Comment: what version of windows are you on? Which version of cygwin are you using?

Comment: This is an interesting question, the instructions provided below did not work whilst attempting to compile on a cygwin instance.  Can we get a comprehensive list of steps and dependencies that are needed to make this work and move through the entire process?

Answer (score 2):

@Yaakov's proposal is actually quite close, but
to compile fish 2.0 successfully you would need to comment/remove offending line from fallback.h and invoke configuration with:

```
./configure CXXFLAGS='-I/usr/include -I/usr/include/ncursesw'
```

after which you should be able to `make` and `make install`

Answer (score 0):

You got a false negative in a configure test because `<term.h>` was not found; you need to pass `CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/ncurses` as an argument to configure to get this to work.